# How to get an infinite scrolling system to work within an iframe

Tags: iframe, scroll, embed, tumblr, infinite-scroll

I am trying to embed a tumblr blog within an iframe on my website:

**Tumblr:** http://architectural-review.tumblr.com

**Webside:** http://www.architectural-review.com/story.aspx?storyCode=8630232&preview=1&hash=AA251CC88264E33B8E824AEE418F1168

The problem I'm having is that the tumblr is using infinite scrolling to load more posts as the user scrolls down. However when embeded in the iframe the tumblr doesn't will not recognize that the use has reached the bottom of the page and so stops loading more posts.

Is there a way of either forcing the tubmlr to load all its posts straight away or getting the iframe to tell the tumblr to load more posts?

Thanks

Phin

Comment: Did the suggested solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to set the `scrollTop` property?
this will maybe trigger the scroll-event.

an alternative could be [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) `$('iframeId').scroll()`.